How to Serialize nested GM2MField in Django Rest Framework Serializer?
I'm trying to serialize a Django model field called GM2MField using Django Rest Framework's serializers. However, I'm encountering difficulty when it comes to including this field within my serializer. Here's what my model and serializer look like:
#models.py
from gm2m import GM2MField

class Collection(models.Model):
    app = models.ForeignKey(Apps, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    rows = GM2MField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

#serializers.py
from gm2m_relations.serializers import GM2MSerializer

class CollectionSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    rows = GM2MSerializer(
        {
            SomeRow: SomeRowSerializer(),
            Collection: #how can i serialize this field
        },
        many=True
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = Collection
        exclude = ['app']

As you can see, the rows field in the Collection model is of type GM2MField, which is a generic Many-to-Many field. I want to include this field in my serializer, but I'm not sure how to properly serialize it.
Could someone provide guidance on how to properly serialize the Collection model within the GM2MField in my serializer? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!
